# Page wont refresh

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am automating interaction with a website to upload a file and download the result.  Not often, but once in awhile the site never loads.  I get the following error.

```
[302.321][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 299.536
[302.323][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.003
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout
(Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 
(e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.2.9200 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 300.01 seconds
```

The script has run through using both the negative and positive path through the if statement.  However, if nothing appears on the page at all, it just fails rather than refreshing.

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);      
    driver.get("http://apps.gdgps.net/apps_file_upload.php");
    System.out.println("test a");

    List<WebElement> upload = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[class*='upfile_ultimo']"));
    if (upload.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("failed");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[id='upload_button']")));
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        System.out.println("next");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class*='upfile_ultimo']")).click();
    }
    else
    {
        upload.get(0).click();
    }
```

I am able to manually refresh the page and it immediately loads and continues on.

Comment: Can you phrase a question? I think it's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: are you getting `TimedOutException` ??

Comment: @GaurangShah, he does according the output he posted.

Comment: yeah, I realize that, so I put that in answer.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing appears on the page script are bound to fail as you haven't handled the exceptions.

Following line would throw the **TimeoutException**

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[id='upload_button']")));
```

So, if you want to continue your script event though exception occurs, you could simply catch that exception.

```
    try{
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[id='upload_button']")));
    }catch (TimeoutException te){
        System.out.print("Timeout for waiting for element");
    }
```

However in your case, the best solution is.

- Increase the explicit wait to `30 seconds` to more
- Set the page timeout. 
  `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  However, the problem persists.  I have added your code before the if statement and in the middle of the if statement where the wait.until already existed.  I am still getting the errors, though. Is there a different placement for this code that I have not tried?

Comment: on which line you are getting error, what error you are getting.

Comment: The error is the same from my initial post.  The real problem is that I need this window to refresh if it doesn't load at all.  That happens frequently enough that it's a problem.  My code just freezes up, errors out, and dies.  I was trying to program it to refresh the browser if after (something like) 5 minutes passed with indication the browser had loaded.  I can perform that manually and it works, but have not been able to automate it.  Thank you, again, for your expertise.